# gulp sass в css форматирование

Tags: css, gulp, sass

Ребята очень глупый вопрос. но при написании кода в sass через Gulp он все отлично создается в css но если делема которая меня немного бесит, чисто визуально, код создаватся стал такого вот вида, пишу в Sublime 3

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #eef3f5;
  color: #131313;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  padding-top: 40px; }
```

все супер, но хотелось бы чтобы последняя скобка все таки была внизу. как я привык... как исправить ума не приложу, возможно это настройки самого саблайм? хотя врядли же...

Comment: многа ты хочешь

Answer (score 0):

Смысл что то исправлять в файле который на выходе после сборки gulp. Его никто никогда не модифицирует и обычно он минифицирован и код в нем всегда в одну строку, так что не нежно в этот файл смотреть только если что то не получилось на странице.

Answer (score 0):

У node-sass есть опция [outputStyle](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#outputstyle)

```
.pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'expanded'}))
```